# Too many output error in matlab 2013b

Tags: matlab

I am suffering an error whose identifier is 'MATLAB:TooManyOutputs' in MATLAB 2013b
The line which produces this error is

```
 [initCorrs, CorrCosts, ColorT, TempCorr] =  initial(Src, Ref, Para);

  (disp('Loading Images and Initialing ...');
    Src  = double(imread([folder '\' Src_path])) / 255.0;
    Ref  = double(imread([folder '\' Ref_path])) / 255.0;
    Para = [];)
```

**ERROR:**

> "Error using initial Too many output arguments. Error in main>initializeM (line 28) [initCorrs, CorrCosts, ColorT, TempCorr] = initial(Src, Ref, Para); Error in main (line 8) initializeM('2.jpg', '1.jpg', folder);"

Comment: Please post the *full* error message and stack trace, not your paraphrasing.

Comment: This is he full error message         "Error using initial
Too many output arguments.

Error in main>initializeM (line 28)
    [initCorrs, CorrCosts, ColorT, TempCorr] =  initial(Src, Ref, Para);

Error in main (line 8)
    initializeM('2.jpg', '1.jpg', folder);"

Answer (score 3):

According to [official matlab docs](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/initial.html), the syntax for initial is:

```
initial(sys,x0)
initial(sys,x0,Tfinal)
initial(sys,x0,t)
initial(sys1,sys2,...,sysN,x0)
initial(sys1,sys2,...,sysN,x0,Tfinal)
initial(sys1,sys2,...,sysN,x0,t)
[y,t,x] = initial(sys,x0)
[y,t,x] = initial(sys,x0,Tfinal)
[y,t,x] = initial(sys,x0,t)
```

Therefore, max 3 elements in output. And you put 4, so here is the problem.

Comment: incase i am giving input with 3 elements means its show error as "Not enough input arguments."

Comment: He was talking about the number of _output_ arguments.

Comment: First, your link is already dead. And second, stop looking, you are using `initial` wrongly: `[initCorrs, CorrCosts, ColorT, TempCorr]` is 4 outputs when you must have 3. That's why you are getting an error message containing "too many output arguments"